# No 'get_network_driver' in Python3 Napalm on Ubuntu Network Automation Container

Tags: python-3.x, networking, containers, napalm, gns3

I'm currently working on Network Automation Container in GNS3. While I'm trying to use napalm lib, I'm getting either or these two errors:

- "**ImportError: cannot import name 'get_network_driver' from partially initialized module 'napalm' (most likely due to a circular import                                                                                   ) (/root/napalm.py)**"
- "**AttributeError: partially initialized module 'napalm' has no attribute 'get_network_driver' (most likely due to a circular import)**"

I checked Python version on this machine and it's 3.8.3 so the napalm is supported here.
Does anyone know what can cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

Tl;dr: Don't name your file `napalm.py`

Your file is called `napalm.py` and the library is also called napalm. When you do a `from napalm import get_network_driver`, Python looks in your file `napalm.py` for `get_network_driver`. So the best thing would be to rename your file.

Answer (score -1):

```
There are 2 probable issues:
1. The nano files you created and saved in the appliance
2. Python - Netmiko - Napalm versions compatibility

Network Automation Appliance (NAA) comes preinstalled with Python 2.7 & 3.8 + 
Netmiko 3.0 + Napalm 2.5.0.

You can see this with >>> pip freeze

Solution:
Use a fresh Network Automation Appliance (NAA) in your GNS3 topology.
Re-install Napalm in NAA with >>> pip install napalm
(This will auto-install Napalm's compatible version of Netmiko)

Check the version of Napalm and Netmiko installed with >>> pip freeze

napalm==2.5.0
netmiko==2.4.2
paramiko==2.7.1
```